# Microsoft Graph API BETA - retrieving calendar for event returns unexpected calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I ran into an issue when working with the Microsoft Graph API BETA version (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/beta-overview)

I retrieve event details by calling the API endpoint (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/event_get#http-request)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/beta/me/events/{id}
```

which returns me an event resource as described here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/event

When I want to fetch it's calendar details afterwards by requesting

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events/{id}/calendar
```

it results in a valid calendar response containing my default calendar instead of the calendar this item belongs to when working directly in https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/Month

Did anyone else run into this issue? What's the correct way to use the API when trying to fetch the calendar information for an event resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is a duplicate of

**Office365 Unified API, get calendar ID from Events ID** ([Office365 Unified API, get calendar ID from Events ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435053/office365-unified-api-get-calendar-id-from-events-id/44760392))

which was answered by @GiedriusL ([Office365 Unified API, get calendar ID from Events ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435053/office365-unified-api-get-calendar-id-from-events-id/44760392#answer-44760392))

> It could be OK in some scenarios, but if you are playing with group calendars, then it will not help.